# How to translate "My history"?

Tags: traduction

"Mon histoire" would be interpreted as "My story" wouldn't it? Would it be correct to say "Mon historique" or simply "Historique"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Histoire* encompass both history and story meanings (which slightly overlap), depending on the context.

*Mon histoire* usually means "The story of my life" which looks to be what you are looking for.

*Mon historique* is odd, it usually means: "my logs".

Comment: For clarity, I believe jlliagre means “my written logs,” in case anyone else stumbles over what felled trees have to do with *son historique.*

Comment: Actually, "logs" or "written logs" is more accurate to the context in which I'm trying to use this phrase, not "the story of my life." Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

According to WordReference, a story is a fictional tale. So to say "mon histoire", I'd use "My history".

References:

- [Story](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/story)
- [History](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/history)

Answer (score 1):

Good answers posted already, I just wanted to hint at the possible use of

> Mon parcours

Even if not literal, in the case of a person it might be a better option, more humane and less formal/pretentious/academic.